# Why UE Intellisense not working? (Mac m1)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense, unreal-engine4, apple-m1

I was a windows user and I am a Unreal Engine beginner, so after I bought Macbook Pro m1 I installed the UE 4.27, and VS code so, I got so many errors in VS Code that says `cannot open source file "stdlib.h" (dependency of "PROJECT_LOCATION")` I didn't have any clue what was that so I made a deep search about it, and I saw that everyone gets the same error, I just had to install something called UE Intellisense so I did! but its not working either. I did what internet says! I tried literally everything, reinstalling, changing the directory, using extra extensions, moving folders to somewhere else, etc. There was so many ways that made nonsense but I tried and I still get the same error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the forums you will see that UE5 is barely supported on x64 Mac, and even less so on M1.  As far as your question specifically goes your best bet in getting Unreal to work is to install XCode, that is what is the most supported on Mac.  Since you are on a M1 Mac with ARM architecture you are also going to be forced to set up compilation through Rosetta.  From browsing the Unreal forums it looks like most people working with your setup are building from source which you have to get from the Epic Games GitHub.